# Reference directory install path in registry value using Wix

Tags: reference, wix, directory, registry

I want to save the path of my application, installed with wix, in the windows registry. I tried the following:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\company\InstallLocation" Value="[#INSTALLLOCATION]" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

where `INSTALLLOCATION` is the Directory Id of the folder in Wix, but this doesn't work. It seems that the [#id] syntax is only for files...

I saw the following question but the blog he references seemingly is no more:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521825/saving-install-path-to-registry

Comment: And now the question itself is no more

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just remove the `#` sign, leave only `[INSTALLLOCATION]` and it should work. The `#` symbol referes to file keys. Without the `#` it refers to a property and [all directories become properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368295.aspx). See [the article about Formatted data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609.aspx) for more details.

Comment: The # symbol referes to file keys.  Without the # refers to a property and all directories become properties.

Comment: See "Formatted (Windows)" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find how to do this but it seems the wix documentation is not that great.. (I think).

Comment: I get a warning with this: "Warning: The 'WIXUI_INSTALLDIR' Property contains '[INSTALLLOCATION]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes." http://stackoverflow.com/a/7180242/1061602