# WiX Property Reference Another Property

Tags: reference, wix, properties

I am trying to create multiple shortcuts to my application that pass different arguments on the commandline by using the `Arguments` attribute of the [Shortcut](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_shortcut.htm) element. I want to be able to reference an existing property from another property in my **WiX** file.

I want to be able to create a shortcut by referencing the `ARGUMENTS` property via:

```
<Component Id="MyAppProgramMenuShortcut" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
        Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\MyAppShortcut" Type="string"
        Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
    <Shortcut Id="ProgramMenuShortcutMyApp" Directory="ProgramMenuDir"
        Name="MyApp" Target="[SHORTCUT_TARGET]"
        Arguments="-jar myApp.jar [ARGUMENTS]" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
        Icon="logo.ico" />
</Component>
```

I've tried something equivalent to:

```
<Property Id="PROGRAM_FILES">C:\Program Files</Property>
<Property Id="MY_APP_DIR">[PROGRAM_FILES]\MyApp</Property>
<Property Id="ARGUMENTS">[MY_APP_DIR]\fileA.xml [MY_APP_DIR]\fileB.xml</Property>
```

but then I get this warning when passing it through *candle.exe*:

> warning CNDL1077 : The 'MY_APP_DIR' Property contains
>   '[PROGRAM_FILES]' in its value which is an illegal reference to
>   another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property
>   reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the
>   value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value
>   attributes.

So, based on the suggestion in the warning I switched to something equivalent to:

```
<CustomAction Id="PROGRAM_FILES" Property="PROGRAM_FILES" Value="C:\Program Files"/>
<CustomAction Id="MY_APP_DIR" Property="MY_APP_DIR" Value="[PROGRAM_FILES]\MyApp"/>
<CustomAction Id="ARGUMENTS" Property="ARGUMENTS" Value="[MY_APP_DIR]\fileA.xml [MY_APP_DIR]\fileB.xml"/>
```

and I get no warnings or errors, but the problem is that when I install the application the shortcuts don't have the arguments in the target field.

Am I not doing something that I should be doing? Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need properties for Program Files or your product's install directory. Use `[#FileId]` to refer to the complete path to that file.

Also, if you want multiple shortcuts, just have multiple `Shortcut` elements with different `Arguments` attributes. If you want one of several shortcuts, you can have multiple `Component`s with `Shortcut`s and use a `Condition` to install only one of them.

Comment: I did not know about the `[#FileId]` syntax. Thanks. The only issue is a **warning LGHT1076 : ICE69** when passed through _light.exe_. So, it works but it's not recommended since I'm using the file reference in different `Component`s.

Comment: An ICE69 *warning* is OK if you always ensure that the components are in the same feature. ICE warnings almost always mean "hey, this is something you should look at to make sure it's what you meant," not that something is or isn't recommended.