# Wix: Cannot call DISM from Wix CustomAction

Tags: cmd, wix, dism

Wix 3.10

After reading the article ([Run ExeCommand in customAction as Administrator mode in Wix Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484478/run-execommand-in-customaction-as-administrator-mode-in-wix-installer)),
I have used a deferred CustomAction with attribute Impersonate="no", calling a batch file with DISM command.

```xml
    <Property Id="CMD">
      <DirectorySearch Id="CmdFolder" Path="[SystemFolder]" Depth="1">
        <FileSearch Id="CmdExe" Name="cmd.exe"  />
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="SXSPATH" Secure="yes" Value="SXSFOLDER" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="SXSFOLDER" />
    </Directory>


    <CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionData" Return="check" Property="OfflineSxSInstall" Value="[SXSFOLDER]" />

    <CustomAction Id="OfflineSxSInstall" Property="CMD" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="/c &quot;&quot;[#file_configure.bat]&quot; &quot;[SXSFOLDER]&quot;&quot;" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="OfflineSxSInstall" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Sadly, always DISM returns error 11 "You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit version of DISM.
Please use the version of DISM that corresponds to your computer's architecture"....

Firstly, I have tried to call proper CMD.exe and DISM.exe for the 64bit Windows 2012R2 test environment, ..... but always returns same error despite the absolute path of DISM, changing Path="[SystemFolder]" to "[System64Folder]"...

Then I found an article with Similar phenomenon (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e25c27cf-ca6d-4079-90a1-8201ffc503e5/dism-gives-error-11?forum=w8itprogeneral) It tells me that it derived from lack of permission...

Currently I have tried to solve the problem by using schtasks.exe clearly running as Administrator...(Probably with login and password by Wix public parameter....user input with Wix UI window, ugly....)

configure.bat

```
setlocal

echo ＠Starting Installation of IIS Role Services and .NET Framework.... ＠%DATE%_%TIME%   >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1


REM cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
cd >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1
echo %1 >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1
SET SXS_SOURCE_PATH=%1

DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /Source:%SXS_SOURCE_PATH% >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1
if !ERRORLEVEL! neq 0 (
    ECHO interrupting Installation of IIS Role Services and .NET Framework....＠%DATE%_%TIME%  >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1
    EXIT /B 100
)       


DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /all /Source:%SXS_SOURCE_PATH% >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1

if !ERRORLEVEL! neq 0 (
    ECHO ＠interrupting Installation of IIS Role Services and .NET Framework....＠%DATE%_%TIME%  >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1
    EXIT /B 100
)       



echo ＠Complete  Installation of IIS Role Services and .NET Framework....＠%DATE%_%TIME%   >> C:\temp\test_configure.txt 2>&1

endlocal
exit /B 0
```

Any ideas? I'm afraid that I must face something big thing like the DISM API....

P.S.
Following kind @Chris Riccio's advice, I stopped using batch file, and QuietExec works fine, while the AddIISComponent command is not so long. (If I used the comment out command, LIGHT warned "LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: CustomAction, Column: Target, Key(s): AddDISMComponent." )

```xml
    <CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionData" Return="check" Property="AddDISMComponent" Value="[SXSFOLDER]" />

    <!--<CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent' Property='DISMComponent' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:NetFx3 /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>-->
    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent' Property='DISMComponent' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:NetFx3 /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent" After="CostFinalize" />
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have currently tried to call multiple QuietExec-DISM commands chopping up the long parameters...

Not smart....

```
    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent1' Property='DISMComponent1' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent1" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent2' Property='DISMComponent2' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent2" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent1" After="CostFinalize" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent2" After="AddDISMComponent1" />
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent1" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent2" After="DISMComponent1"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in Wix QuietExec custom action to run the dism command line - this should simplify the installer quite a bit

```
    <CustomAction Id='AddIISComponent' Property='IISComponent' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole /all' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="IISComponent" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="AddIISComponent" After="CostFinalize" />
        <Custom Action="IISComponent" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here's a complete [sample](https://gitlab.com/chris2/wix-toolset-examples/tree/master/InstallIISWithDISM)

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I need to use the installer on customer environment which might not be available online WindowsUpdate...May I ask you how to set "/Source:" directory?

Comment: You should be able to add the source parameter to the command line just as you have in your example.

Comment: Thank you again for my basic question. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Not smart as I expected....but works.

```
    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent1' Property='DISMComponent1' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent1" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent2' Property='DISMComponent2' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent2" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent3' Property='DISMComponent3' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent3" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent4' Property='DISMComponent4' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent4" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent5' Property='DISMComponent5' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent5" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent6' Property='DISMComponent6' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent6" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent7' Property='DISMComponent7' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent7" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent8' Property='DISMComponent8' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent8" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent9' Property='DISMComponent9' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent9" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent10' Property='DISMComponent10' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent10" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent11' Property='DISMComponent11' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent11" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent12' Property='DISMComponent12' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent12" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent13' Property='DISMComponent13' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent13" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent14' Property='DISMComponent14' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent14" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent15' Property='DISMComponent15' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent15" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent16' Property='DISMComponent16' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent16" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent17' Property='DISMComponent17' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent17" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent18' Property='DISMComponent18' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent18" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent19' Property='DISMComponent19' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent19" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent20' Property='DISMComponent20' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent20" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent21' Property='DISMComponent21' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent21" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <CustomAction Id='AddDISMComponent22' Property='DISMComponent22' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /all /Source:[SXSFOLDER]' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="DISMComponent22" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent1" After="CostFinalize" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent2" After="AddDISMComponent1" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent3" After="AddDISMComponent2" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent4" After="AddDISMComponent3" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent5" After="AddDISMComponent4" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent6" After="AddDISMComponent5" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent7" After="AddDISMComponent6" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent8" After="AddDISMComponent7" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent9" After="AddDISMComponent8" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent10" After="AddDISMComponent9" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent11" After="AddDISMComponent10" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent12" After="AddDISMComponent11" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent13" After="AddDISMComponent12" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent14" After="AddDISMComponent13" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent15" After="AddDISMComponent14" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent16" After="AddDISMComponent15" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent17" After="AddDISMComponent16" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent18" After="AddDISMComponent17" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent19" After="AddDISMComponent18" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent20" After="AddDISMComponent19" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent21" After="AddDISMComponent20" />
      <Custom Action="AddDISMComponent22" After="AddDISMComponent21" />

      <Custom Action="DISMComponent1" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent2" After="DISMComponent1"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent3" After="DISMComponent2"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent4" After="DISMComponent3"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent5" After="DISMComponent4"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent6" After="DISMComponent5"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent7" After="DISMComponent6"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent8" After="DISMComponent7"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent9" After="DISMComponent8"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent10" After="DISMComponent9"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent11" After="DISMComponent10"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent12" After="DISMComponent11"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent13" After="DISMComponent12"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent14" After="DISMComponent13"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent15" After="DISMComponent14"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent16" After="DISMComponent15"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent17" After="DISMComponent16"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent18" After="DISMComponent17"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent19" After="DISMComponent18"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent20" After="DISMComponent19"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent21" After="DISMComponent20"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
      <Custom Action="DISMComponent22" After="DISMComponent21"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 

    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```